# Angularjs : What is the best way to let Binding Data later update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

If I have a ng-repeat directive bind with my initial data,

```
 <!-- list 1-->
 <li ng-repeat="data in datas">{{data.name}}</li>
```

and I change the data by another ng-repeat and ng-model directive,

```
 <!-- list 2-->
 <li ng-repeat="data in datas">
     <input type="text" ng-model="data.name">
 </li>
```

In Angular way, any method can do list 1 ng-repeat data refresh not immediately (after I click a Save button)?

```
<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a second (temporary) clone to make the changes and copy the changes over to the actual object using **[angular.copy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy)**.

```
The actual list:
<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.name}} (id: {{item.id}})
</li></ul>

Edit the list:
<ul><li ng-repeat="item in tempCopy">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" />
</li></ul>

<button ng-click="persistChanges()">Save</button>
<button ng-click="discardChanges()">Discard</button
```

In your controller:

```
/* Persist the changes */
$scope.persistChanges  = function () {
    angular.copy($scope.model.tempCopy, $scope.model.items);
};
/* Discard the changes */
$scope.discardChanges  = function () {
    angular.copy($scope.model.items, $scope.model.tempCopy);
};
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/h5ZY3/)**.

Finally, there is a similar example on the Angular docs on **[angular.copy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy)**.

Comment: It's exactly what I want. Your Answer is very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are creating new items within `datas` by extending the array by one element? If this is so, why not use a different model for the form and push the result onto the array `data` when the save button is clicked?

Similarly, when editing an item, clone the array element and make it the model for the resulting form, then modify the original array element when the save button is clicked.